# How to do fo to pdf transform without accessing w3c?

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, w3c

Is it possible to do fo to pdf transform via java.xml.transform without accessing www.w3.org?  There are, of course, references to this website in the schema, etc.  Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions">
```

Is there a way to move files to a local machine to avoid going to the w3 server?  I know this isn't ideal, but the ip accessing w3 is currently getting http403 back so I need a temporary workaround while we address the larger problem.  Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: If your Java app is accessing w3.org, you need an [entity resolver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things that look like attributes that start with `xmlns` are namespace declarations.  Neither your XSLT processor nor your XSL formatter will access the W3C servers because of the namespace declarations.

Namespaces are just a way to disambiguate elements that have the same local name.  In your case, the `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` namespace URI lets the XSLT processor recognise the elements (and some attributes) that are significant for XSLT processing, and the `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format` namespace URI lets the XSL formatter recognise the elements that are defined by the XSL specification.

The URI that is the value of the namespace declaration doesn't need to be a resolvable URL.  But for your XSLT and XSL-FO processing to work, they do have to be those URLs that you are using.

I would refer you to the Namespaces in XML specification, but I'm having a similar 403 problem myself. This tutorial from xml.com explains namespaces: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html